# How do I properly format this MongoDB update clause?

Tags: c#, mongodb, insert-update

I have the following document:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "55e1f841ff149c2228a5c33d"
},
"Status": "Open",
"Date": "8/30/2015",
"ContestName": "Test Contest",
"SearchableContestName": "test contest",
"ClassName": "Test",
"SearchableClassName": "test",
"Judges": [
    {
        "Name": "First Last",
        "IsHeadJudge": null,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "55e20962ff149c1f70d1aab0"
        },
        "ContestScores": null
    },
    {
        "Name": "Another Name",
        "IsHeadJudge": null,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "55e20947ff149c1f70d1aaaf"
        },
        "ContestScores": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6
        ]
    },
```

...

There are multiple judges in this list.  I want to selectively update only the contest scores for the "First Last" name individual.   I'm having difficulty figuring out the proper way to build my filters for this.  I have:

```
 public async void UpdateContestScores(ContestJudge judgeData, ObjectId contestId)
    {
        var contests = _db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("contests");
        var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
        var updateFilter = builder.Eq("_id", contestId) & builder.Eq("Judges.Name", judgeData.Name);

        var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("Judges.ContestScores", judgeData.ContestScores);

        await contests.UpdateOneAsync(updateFilter, update);
    }
```

This throws a bulk update error of some form.  How do I go about updating this empty contest score field?  I'm unsure of the proper filter syntax for such a thing.

Comment: You are missing the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator  which is used to identifity the matched position of the "Judges" array as in `"Judges.$.ContentScores"`. Without it the error will be something along the lines of "cannot traverse array element" since you are not saying which particular index of the array to use.

Comment: Unreal.  That was it.  If you want to add that as an Answer I'll accept it.  Thanks.